# Get float values with more than 3 digits after decimal points

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called SMFeechallanhdr in a SQL Server database. It has 3 major columns that I am concerned with these are: `amount`, `adjustamount` and `balance amount`. All of these columns are of float type. These columns most have values that have 0 to 3 digits after decimal point. For instance these columns have values like 20, 20.1, 20.43, 20.456. But in some cases these columns may contain values like 1.0000000054 or 9.333333333354. That is, some values have more than 3 digits after decimal point. I need a query that could find me only those values that have more than 3 digits after decimal point. I have tried chatgpt but it all of its suggestion have proved to be useless.

[image]

Please refer to this image. The query should return records like number 26,29,30,33,34, 35 and all such records.

Comment: Don't use FLOAT to store monetary values. Use decimal! https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: _I have tried chatgpt but it all of its suggestion have proved to be useless._ This is the correct answer.

Comment: @jarlh I know decimal should have been used here. But I didn't designed the DB and it already has so much data now and my company has told me to do this. And clean such data.

Comment: If you'd like somebody to provide a tested code-based answer then please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76529448/edit) your question to include the sample data as DDL+DML script, or at least a markdown table. Nobody should have to transcribe data from screen shots to explore possibilities for you.

Comment: So what are you actually going to do when you identify all of the rows with excessive decimal places? They are still `float` data types in the table, aka. [approximate numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql), so no amount of correcting is going to make those fractional parts get stored with just three decimal places. You need to encourage the business to correct the table design as part of the clean up.

Comment: The solution to clean the data is to fix the database design. You've probably already suffered problems with rounding and similar issues, so the data is already flawed.

Comment: This is basically a school management system as you can probably imagine and this table holds the fee vouchers of students. We have applied all sorts of validations and stuff from frontend and backend to make sure that data that gets to the table is as we want it and it is perfectly fine in the new cases made after applying these validations and stuff. The issue is with the data already in the table. Such dirty records are creating problems when these challans get collected.

Comment: Obviously the right approach is to make decimal columns along with all the validations. And I will push the manage to improve the database, but the old data has to be corrected anyway

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: if you dont wanna convert the type, just run UPDATE t set balanceamount = CAST(balanceamount AS DECIMAL(19,3)) from sometableOfYourChoosing t;

Comment: You could also ask the student to pay you in a currency that uses that operates using factors of 2, as that'll then match your data... Though I don't think there are any.

Comment: @ThomA Bitcoin?